# How to deploy React on IIS?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, web-deployment

When working on localhost, the app is assumed to be on root of the local dev server

> localhost:50001/index.html

But when deploying to a remote IIS server, there are other web apps running there, and each individual app must be created as an "Application" (IIS terminology)

So for example, the 'Default Web Site' is on port 80; other apps (also on port 80) have their own AppName.

> MYSERVERNAME/App1/
>   MYSERVERNAME/App2/
>   MYSERVERNAME/MyReactApp/

So now to get to my React App i have an additional path
    http://MYSERVERNAME/MyReactApp/index.html

The index.html produced by 'npm run build' contains absolute paths;
To make my deployment work, I manually edited the index.html to contain relative paths

So for example, instead of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.d17bed58.js"></script>
```

I added a .(dot) in front of all paths to get:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/main.d17bed58.js"></script>
```

This works mostly, and all scripts load initially. BUT I am not happy with the result, because any links and client-side routes (i.e from react-router) that I click within the app, will revert to assume the app is hosted on the root of the webserver. i.e.

> http://MYSERVERNAME/
>
> http://MYSERVERNAME/Home
>
> http://MYSERVERNAME/MyWorkOrder/
>
> http://MYSERVERNAME/MyWorkOrder/123456

Furthermore, if I type any of the links directly on the browser (or refresh the page), it will fail obviously.

To recap. the question is I need to maintain the "true" path http://MYSERVERNAME/myReactApp at all times, when deploying to IIS. How to do that?

Comment: Nice. -1 immediately 1 minute after posting. Thanks, Mr Know It All. wish i was as smart as you :-)

Comment: Wasn't me. However, this is totally unrelated to IIS, so the title is somewhat misleading. Your issue could be better read as, e.g., "How to load a React application from a non-root folder" or something like that.

Comment: @ssice I take your point.. but I am using IIS specifically in combo with React so the title combination seems fine to me.

Comment: But it does not have to make sense to you internally. It *needs* to make sense for all of us and future visitors.

Comment: @joedotnot for me your title makes a lot of sense, I have the same problem and your post comes from the search immediately, so you are right man, don't worry about negative comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i ended up doing

1) After npm run build, change absolute paths to relative paths within index.html (example href="./etc..." and src="./etc...")

2) use basename in <BrowserRouter basename="/MyReactApp"/> (as per the answer by @mehamasum)

3) And finally, when doing page refresh on a non-existent SERVER route, you need to redirect what would otherwise be a 404, to the index.html, and let the client-side react-router library do its job. How? In IIS Manager, go to the IIS section\Error Pages\double-click\Edit 404 Status code, and in the 'Edit Custom Error Page' dialog, choose 'Execute a URL on this site', and enter the absolute path /MyReactApp/index.html

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths):

**Building for Relative Paths**

By default, Create React App produces a build assuming your app is hosted at the server root.
To override this, specify the `homepage` in your `package.json`, for example:

```
"homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath",
```

This will let Create React App correctly infer the root path to use in the generated HTML file.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.xyz.js"></script>
```

will become:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/relativepath/static/js/main.xyz.js"></script>
```

---

If you are using `react-router@^4`, you can root `<Link>`s using the `basename` prop on any `<Router>`.
More information [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string).

For example:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/calendar"/>
<Link to="/today"/> // renders <a href="/calendar/today">
```

Comment: Ok. Give me time to work on it and I will come back to mark your answer. BUT I don't want to hardcode a server name (just the relative path is fine) .. e.g. http://DEVSERVER/MyApp , http://UATSERVER/MyApp , http://PRODSERVER/MyApp

Comment: AFAIK, the CRA will not use the domain name anywhere. For example, `foo.com/MyApp` and `bar.com/MyApp` will result in the same build i.e. `src=/MyApp/static/js/main.xyz.js`

Comment: Ok. But you asked me to use "homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/MyApp" in the package.json. So i would have to build 3 times for 3 different servers? I want to build only once. (but thanks.. one step at a time first).

Comment: This worked for me and seems like a better answer than the accepted one. Instead of manually editing paths just let the build script do the work for you. As @mehamasum mentioned in another comment, the domain does not matter for the build, It just uses the relative path. Also, if you are using hash router you don't have to worry about settings `basename` on routes.